# Function reading from Console.In returns previous values

Tags: f#

In order to learn F# I'm trying to solve the Codingame puzzle [The Descent](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/the-descent)

- 8 numbers are read from Console.In.ReadLine()
- the index of the highest number should be printed
- repeat 8 times

Below code works for the first run, but appears to give the exact same result after the first loop for different inputs.
Running the idxWithHighestValue function in Interactive with an array instead of reading from console gives the desired results.

Expected behavior:
[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2] => 0
[0,8,7,6,5,4,3,2] => 1

Actual behavior:
[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2] => 0
[0,8,7,6,5,4,3,2] => 0

```
open System

let highestMountain =
    let readEightInputs =
        let readlines n = Array.init n (fun _ -> Console.In.ReadLine() |> int)
        readlines 8
    let idxWithHighestValue list = 
        list
        |> Seq.mapi (fun i v -> i, v)
        |> Seq.maxBy snd
        |> fst
    idxWithHighestValue readEightInputs

(* game loop *)
while true do   
    (* Write an action using printfn *)
    (* To debug: Console.Error.WriteLine("Debug message") *)

    printfn "%i" highestMountain(* The index of the mountain to fire on. *)
    ()
```

Is there something wrong with my readEightInputs function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `highestMountain` is just an `int` value, but you want it to be a *function* that reads console inputs and *returns* an `int` i.e. its type signature should be `unit -> int` instead of just `int`. Simply adding `()` (unit) to the declaration makes it a function that can be called—not just a value to be calculated once. Then you can call that function in your loop:

```
let highestMountain () =
    let readEightInputs =
        let readlines n = Array.init n (fun _ -> Console.In.ReadLine() |> int)
        readlines 8
    let idxWithHighestValue list = 
        list
        |> Seq.mapi (fun i v -> i, v)
        |> Seq.maxBy snd
        |> fst
    idxWithHighestValue readEightInputs

while true do
    let result = highestMountain()
    printfn "%i" result (* The index of the mountain to fire on. *)
    ()
```

In your example, the code in `highestMountain` is only evaluated *once* to get its final `int` value and there's no need to evaluate it again; as far as F# is concerned its value could never change. Making it a *function* means you can call it as many times as you need to get different inputs.

Here's one way to refactor this code by extracting generally useful functions:

```
let readLines count = // int -> string[]
  [| for _ in 1 .. count -> Console.ReadLine() |]
let maxValueIndex source = // seq<'a> -> int
  source
  |> Seq.mapi (fun i v -> i, v)
  |> Seq.maxBy snd
  |> fst
while true do
  let highMountainIdx = readLines 8 |> Seq.map int |> maxValueIndex
  printfn "%i" highMountainIdx
  ()
```

Instead of nesting all the functions in an omni-function, this extracts them as generally useful, top-level functions and pipes them together; and the omni-function `highestMountain` is gone. There's also a separation of concerns between reading console lines and converting them to `int`s. If you still wanted that high-level function, it's now possible to construct it as a *composition* of your other functions:

```
// int -> int
let highestMountain = readLines >> Seq.map int >> maxValueIndex
```

This is now a function that takes a number (of mountains to read in) and returns the index of the largest one, called like `printfn "%i" (highestMountain 8)`. Note that while the `highestMountain` definition has no explicit args, it *is* a function because it's a composition of other functions via `>>` operator. Its arguments are the same as its first function `readLines`, and its return type is that of its final function `maxValueIndex`. This works because the middle (curried) function `Seq.map int` is compatible with the output of `readLines` and the input of `maxValueIndex`.

Comment: aha, noob mistake as expected. Thx :)

Comment: Thx for the extra information. Really learning new things here :)

Answer (score 3):

Taylor Wood has already pointed out that `highestMountain` is just an integer value, not a function. I'll just mention that you ask "Is there something wrong with my readEightInputs function?", but in fact in the code that you've shown us, `readEightInputs` is *also* a value, not a function. In F#, this is a value:

```
let name = (series of expressions)
```

This is a function:

```
let name parameter = (series of expressions)
```

If there's at least one parameter after the name, even if that parameter is the "unit" value `()`, then it's a function, and the series of expressions after the = character will be evaluated each time you call the function. If there are no parameters, then it's a value that's only evaluated once. (BTW, the "unit" value `()` is very useful to know about. Think of this value as an empty tuple: there's only one possible value for an empty tuple, so the type is called `unit` because there can be only one of it).

One more thing I'll mention: your `readEightInputs` value, even if you turned it into a function, seems a bit silly. Why not just use your `readlines` function directly? That `readlines` function is a good, useful function. Instead of `idxWithHighestValue readEightInputs`, you could instead write that line as `idxWithHighestValue (readlines 8)`. Voila: now if it turns out that you have to read ten lines for a later exercise, you can just call `readlines 10`. Code reuse is a good thing.

Comment: I read about Unit, but until now I didn't really get it. Thx :)
Reg the readEightLines: you are probably right, I was just experimenting with how far I should push it