# Declaring a variable without assigning workaround

Tags: f#, functional-programming

i'm writing a small console application in F#.

```
    [<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    high_lvl_funcs.print_opt
    let opt = Console.ReadLine()
    match opt with
    | "0" -> printfn "%A" (high_lvl_funcs.calculate_NDL)
    | "1" -> printfn ("not implemented yet")
    | _ -> printfn "%A is not an option" opt
```

from `module high_lvl_funcs`

```
let print_opt = 
    let options = [|"NDL"; "Deco"|]
    printfn "Enter the number of the option you want"
    Array.iteri (fun i x -> printfn "%A: %A" i x) options

let calculate_NDL =
    printfn ("enter Depth in m")
    let depth = lfuncs.m_to_absolute(float (Console.ReadLine()))
    printfn ("enter amount of N2 in gas (assuming o2 is the rest)")
    let fn2 = float (Console.ReadLine())
    let table = lfuncs.read_table
    let tissue = lfuncs.create_initialise_Tissues ATM WATERVAPOUR
    lfuncs.calc_NDL depth fn2 table lfuncs.loading_constantpressure tissue 0.0

lfuncs.calc_NDL returns a float
```

this produces this

```
Enter the number of the option you want
0: "NDL"
1: "Deco"
enter Depth in m
```

which means it prints what it's suppose to then jumps straight to  `high_lvl_funcs.calculate_NDL`

I wanted it to produce

```
  Enter the number of the option you want
    0: "NDL"
    1: "Deco"
```

then let's assume 0 is entered, and then calculate `high_lvl_funcs.calculate_NDL`

after some thinking and searching i assume this is because F# wants to assign all values before it starts the rest. Then i thought that i need to declaring a variable without assigning it. but people seem to agree that this is bad in functional programming. From another question: [Declaring a variable without assigning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086368/declaring-a-variable-without-assigning)

so my question is, is it possible to rewrite the code such that i get the flow i want and avoid declaring variables without assigning them?

Comment: Also see [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48755597/function-reading-from-console-in-returns-previous-values).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix this by making `calculate_NDL` a *function* of no arguments, instead of a closure that evaluates to a `float`:

```
let calculate_NDL () =
```

Then call it as a function in your `match` like this:

```
match opt with
| "0" -> printfn "%A" (high_lvl_funcs.calculate_NDL())
```

However I'd suggest refactoring this code so that `calculate_NDL` takes any necessary inputs as arguments rather than reading them from the console i.e. read the inputs from the console separately and pass them to `calculate_NDL`.

```
let calculate_NDL depth fn2 =
    let absDepth = lfuncs.m_to_absolute(depth)
    let table = lfuncs.read_table
    let tissue = lfuncs.create_initialise_Tissues ATM WATERVAPOUR
    lfuncs.calc_NDL absDepth fn2 table lfuncs.loading_constantpressure tissue 0.0
```

It's generally a good idea to write as much code as possible as [*pure* functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) that don't rely on I/O (like reading from stdin).

Comment: Same goes for ``print_opt``, it is currently a value but should be a function ``print_opt ()`` instead.

Comment: where do you recommend doing the I/O?
would i use mutable's for I/O